# Login Site Flash.Com Python 1

Tags: python, flash

I would like to know,Python to log into Flash sites, which are not linked to any `HTML` tags.alternate is Selenium rre

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

Look at the documentation and you'll be fine. This library works like a navigator, so you can use it for different kinds of websites.

You can use the ghost mode to work silently.